# How to create a playlist using lis in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filereader

I'm trying to create a UI that allows user's to download mp3s from their computer to a playlist. Right now I've gotten the name of the song and the href of the li pointing to the right song. But now I'm wondering how to play a song on an audio element every time a user clicks the li. Right now this is what it looks like:

[image]

And my state looks like this:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
class DownloadTest extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);

    this.inputRef = React.createRef();

    this.state = {
      files: []
    };
  }



handleClick = event => {

  // Helper code to read file and return promise
  const readFile = (file) => {

    const fileList = [];

    const fileReader = new FileReader();

    // create the promise and return it
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      // if file reader has an error, report it
      fileReader.onerror = (error) => {
        reject({ error })
      }

      // if success, resolve the promise
      fileReader.onload = (e) => {
        resolve({
          name: file.name,
          link: e.target.result
        })
      }

      // start reading the file
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);

    })
  }

  // create all the file reader promises
  // create an array from the files list and use map to generate
  // an array of promises
  const allReaders = Array.from(event.target.files).map(readFile)

  // Now handle the array of promises we just created
  Promise.all(allReaders)
    .then(fileList => {
      console.log(fileList)
      // set the state that we have all the files
      this.setState({ files: fileList });
    })
    .catch(error => { 
       console.error(error)
    });

}

  render() {
     console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <div className="downloadMusic">
      <div className="input">
        <input
          onChange={this.handleClick}
          id="upload-file"
          className="inputName"
          type="file"
          multiple
          ref={this.inputRef}
        />
        </div>
        <div className="audio-player">
        <audio
         src="my_audio_file.ogg"
         autoPlay
         controls
         />
         </div>

        <div>
          <ul ref={this.ulRef}>
            {this.state.files.map((file, index) => (
              <li key={index}>
                <a href={file.link}>{file.name}</a>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DownloadTest;
```

Comment: Can’t you just change the file in the audio element, the same way you would change an image with react? I don’t think you need the filereader? `<audio src={this.state.file}/>`

Comment: @Kokodoko Can you go into more detail about this?

Comment: I created a test and this works 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer, tested and works. You can use the component state to change the audio element source.

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Joy from "./joy.wav"
import Alive from "./alive1.wav"

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      audio: Joy
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ audio: Alive })}>
          Change audio
        </button>
        <audio src={this.state.audio} controls />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean accept the answer? You want me to check it off as the right answer?

Comment: Thanks, haha  That’s how stackoverflow works, otherwise it stays visible as an unanswered question.